# what do these shell escape characters stand for?

Tags: shell, escaping, fish

I saw this on this post: https://superuser.com/questions/409594/fish-control-left-control-right-keybindings
[image]

The escape sequence `\e\[1\;5C`, what does it stand for?

Comment: Is it just double escaped? `5C` = `\` `5D` = `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They stand for <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/how-to-change-previous-next-word-shortcut-in-bash for what these escape sequences do.

Comment: So this is six keys sequence, isn't it too long?

Comment: No, there are much longer escape sequences.